# Jquery ajax GET not returning data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list which holds the models id and an action url

```
 @foreach (var dashboard in Model.dashboard)
            {
                <li class="drop-text clickMe" data-id="@dashboard.DashID" data-action-url="@Url.Action("GetDashboard", "Dashboard")"> @dashboard.DashName</li>
            }
```

here is jquery

```
 $('body').on('click', ".clickMe", function (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    var btn = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= Url.Action("GetDashboard", "Dashboard") %>',
        data: {
            id: btn.data('id')
        },
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#dash-content').html(data);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            $('#dash-content').html('Failed');
        }

    })

});
```

here is my action

```
public ActionResult GetDashboard(int? id)
    {
        var dashID = id;
        if (dashID == null || dashID == 0)
        {
            dashID = 1;
        }

        var getWidgetsQuery = (from widgets in db.widgets
                               where widgets.DashID == dashID
                               select widgets);

        dvm.widgets = getWidgetsQuery.ToList();


        return PartialView(dvm);
    }
```

and this is where the jquery is supposed to insert the contents of the action

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="dash-content">
@Html.Partial("Dashboard", Model);
```

At the moment when the that particular list is pressed it fires the jquery code ok, I have used firebug to confirm this.  However the problem is that the jquery seems to fail and I am unsure why this is.

Comment: what does the ajax response look like on your console or network tab?

Comment: it looks like this
http://gyazo.com/a6ec29dbb8e9bb1ee570eb21ab4291dc
 
This definitely looks wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
 $('body').on('click', ".clickMe", function (e) {

e.stopPropagation();

var btn = $(this);

$.ajax({
    url: '<%= Url.Action("Get", "Dashboard") %>',
    data: {
        id: btn.data('id')
    },
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#dash-content').html(data);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        $('#dash-content').html('Failed');
    }

})
```

});

Comment: I can't work out how this fixes the issue, would you mind explaining *how* this fixes it?

Answer (score 1):

Its not "datatype", it's "dataType". Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using razor syntax on your form:

```
@foreach (var dashboard in Model.dashboard)
```

But you're then using the classic syntax to create the URL:

```
url: '<%= Url.Action("GetDashboard", "Dashboard") %>',
```

That's being treated as a string literal, resulting in a request to

> http://localhost:53658/Dashboard/%3C%=%20Url.Acti...

(The `%3C` is an encoded version of the `<`, followed by the `%=` then the `%20` is an encoded space).

You should change the URL on the ajax call to use razor syntax:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetDashboard", "Dashboard")',
```

Or, as you've set the location on the `data-action-url` attribute you could take it from there:

```
url: btn.data('action-url'),
```